# Differenciate between symbol, number and letter-codepoints in Unicode?

Tags: unicode, text-parsing, codepoint

Unicode has a huge number of codepoints, how can I check wheter a codepoint is a symbol (like "!" or "☭"), a number (like "4" or "৯"), a letter (like "a" or "え") or a control character (are usually not displayed directly)?

Is there any logic behind the position of the character and what kind of character it is (as opposed to just what alphabet it is part of), if not, are there any existing resources which classify which ranges are what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be done through the [General Category property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) of those codepoints. It's part of the canonical `UnicodeData.txt` dataset, and every serious Unicode-related library should have some way for you to get this property.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what general category is useful for, but for this it produces many misleading/unexpected results.

Comment: What do you mean? The General Category clearly distinguishes between 'symbols' (`P*` and `S*`), numbers (`N*`), letters (`L*`) and control characters (`Cc`), among others.

Comment: Well, [see for yourself](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm). They're numbers made up of letters, like VII. To eliminate cases like these, you should normalize to a compatibility normal form rather than a canonical one.